# Functions in StyleSheet.create({}) won't refresh on setState()

Tags: react-native

I was adapting my React Native app to foldable devices and found functions used in StyleSheet.create({}) won't recalculate on setState().

```
// version 1
<IMImage 
  style={{
    width: scaleSize(44),
    height: scaleSize(44),
    borderRadius: scaleSize(22)
  }}
  source={{ uri: avatarUrl }}
/>
// version 2
<IMImage 
  style={styles.itemViewOneImage}
  source={{ uri: avatarUrl }}
/>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    itemViewOneImage: {
        width: scaleSize(44),
        height: scaleSize(44),
        borderRadius: scaleSize(22)
    }
});

export let kScreenWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width

export function scaleSize(size, designWidth = 375) {
  return size * kScreenWidth / 375
}
```

I registered a listener to monitor screen size changes, **kScreenWidth** will change accordingly. But function scaleSize(width) in Component  version 2 won't give new results on screen dimension changes. Version 1 give the correct result though. I'm not sure what's the difference between these 2 versions. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved it by recreating `styles` every time `render()` is called. The function `scaleSize()` might be precalculated and stored as values in `styles`.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and solved it by using React Native's `useWindowDimensions` hook.

useWindowDimensions automatically updates all of its values when screen size or font scale changes. You can get your application window's width and height like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, Text, useWindowDimensions} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const {height, width, scale, fontScale} = useWindowDimensions();
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.header}>Window Dimension Data</Text>
      <Text>Height: {height}</Text>
      <Text>Width: {width}</Text>
      <Text>Font scale: {fontScale}</Text>
      <Text>Pixel ratio: {scale}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 20,
    marginBottom: 12,
  },
});

export default App;
```

You can find more information about this hook here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/usewindowdimensions

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply Saul! useWindowDimensions should be better according to the docs. But the real problem is that I don't know why custom functions in StyleSheet.create({}) won't refresh on setState(). That makes those dimensions won't refresh on a screen size change. Probably those functions are precalculated and stored as values in styles.